# Is this correct? or have a better way?

Tags: grammar

We would like inform you that payment will be pay by 3/29, please provide the bank details for remittance.

Comment: We would like to inform you that remittance will be made by 3/29, please provide the bank details for payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! Your sentence is missing the preposition "to," which needs to be placed before "inform." Tenses need to be kept consistent as well. Lastly, I noticed a comma splice: it is a grammatical error that occurs when a comma is used to separate two independent clauses. Lastly, using "processed" instead of "pay" will make your sentence sound more professional.

As such, the correct sentence is this:

> We would like to inform you that the payment will be processed by 3/29. Please provide the bank details for remittance.

Comment: Thank you for improving my grammar.

Comment: You're most welcome!